# Handling onTouch events in android

Tags: android, custom-controls, touch, scrollview

So I have an autoScrolling scrollView in my class and I want to intercept the user onTouch event so that it stops the scrolling when they click on the scrollView. How will I implement this functionality? I know it has something to do with Overriding the onTouchEvent function, but when I Override this it doesn't work.

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_1_DOWN:
            stopAutoScrolling();
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_1_UP:
            startAutoScrolling();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Look into onInterceptTouchEvent. I think because of the way ScrollView handles touch events, it doesn't call through to the OnTouchEvent method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe when you return true, you are saying you have handled the onTouchEvent.  If you want the normal touch behavior to occur do something like:

return super.onTouchEvent(ev);

That way you call the native code which in your case would perform the scrolling as normal.

Comment: well I want it to stop scrolling when the user clicks on the scrollView and start back up when their finger lifts up. I tried the return super.onTouchEvent(event) and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I read somewhere that I need to Override the onInterceptTouchEvent() function as well?